# Shared memory between N processes c

Tags: c, linux, process, semaphore

My goal here is to try to find a way to have multiple processes reading and writing on a shared memory. Until now I have been able to make only two processes communicate and I can't get around how to make more communicate. I'm making a project in which N processes A write their data on a shared memory and then N processes B read this shared memory and send their own data back to the process A that they decided to talk with. I must use shared memory and semaphores as well.

```
int main()
{


    const char* messageOne = "Hello world , I'm child number 1\n";
    const char* messageTwo = "Hello world , I'm child number 2\n";

    key_t key;
    char *virtualaddr;
    sem_t *get, *put;
    ssize_t numRead = -1;
    int shmid;

    const unsigned int commLen = strlen(messageOne) + 1;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];

    key = ftok("anyfile",'R');

    shmid = shmget(key,1024,0644|IPC_CREAT);
    if (0 > shmid)
    {
        perror("Shared Mem creation error\n");
        exit(1);

    }
    //Attaching  the shared mem to my address space(available across fork)
    virtualaddr = shmat(shmid, (void*)0, 0);


    /*Create two POSIX Named Semaphores, get and put and initialising with 0*/
    get = sem_open("/get", O_CREAT|O_RDWR, 0644, 0);

    put = sem_open("/put", O_CREAT|O_RDWR, 0644, 0);

    // child 1
    switch (fork())
    {
        case -1:
            printf("Error forking child 1!\n");
            exit(1);
        case 0:
            printf("\nChild 1 executing...\n");
            //Referring the semaphores..
            get = sem_open ("/get", O_RDWR);
            put = sem_open ("/put", O_RDWR);

            //Child 1 writing in shared mem
            strcpy (virtualaddr, messageOne);
            //Child 1 signalling that now child 2 can write
            sem_post (get);
            //Child1 waiting for Child2 to write..
            sem_wait (put);
            //Child 1 reading from shared mem
            strcpy (buf, virtualaddr);
            printf("Message received child ONE: %s", buf);
            printf("Exiting child 1...\n");
            _exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    // child 2
    switch (fork())
    {
        case -1:
            printf("Error forking child 2!\n");
            exit(1);
        case 0:
            printf("\nChild 2 executing...\n");
            //Referring the semaphores..
            get = sem_open ("/get", O_RDWR);
            put = sem_open ("/put", O_RDWR);

            //Waiting Till Child 1 has written.
            sem_wait (get);
            //Now child 2 can read from shared memory
            strcpy (buf, virtualaddr);
            //Child 2 writing in shared mem
            strcpy (virtualaddr,messageTwo );
            //Signalling that now Child 1 can read.
            sem_post (put);
            printf("Exiting child 2...\n");
            printf("Message received child TWO: %s", buf);
            _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    printf("Parent waiting for children completion...\n");

    if (wait(NULL) == -1)
    {
        printf("Error waiting.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (wait(NULL) == -1)
    {
        printf("Error waiting.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Parent finishing.\n");
    //Deleting semaphores..
    sem_unlink ("/get");
    sem_unlink ("/put");
    //Deleting Shared Memory.
    shmctl (shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I would like to adapt this code to multiple processes instead of two. If you have other options please feel free to post them.

Comment: "indent code 4 spaces" means you have to indent the whole code block by 4 spaces to let the mark down interpreter recognize it as code. The inline editor tool button **{}** can do this for you. Recently, I realized that `<code>` and `</code>` (or `<pre>` and `</pre>`) seems to work as well.

Comment: What do you want to happen? Do you want one process to write and all the pother processes to then read? Do you want each process to write and a second process to read in a round robin? The solution depends on what you want to do.

Comment: I would like all that all the A processes to write their information and then the B  processes to randomly select one of the A processes and send them their information so that the A processes can read that information and do things according to the value

Answer (score 0):

> Until now I have been able to make only two processes communicate and I can't get around how to make more communicate.

To extend your program for more than one child process pair, it is appropriate to use [*semaphore sets*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/semget.2.html) (of one semaphore per process) rather than plain semaphores. Below is a slightly modified variant of your program which does that for N pairs.

```
/* cc -std=c99 -lrt */
#define _SVID_SOURCE
#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>

int main()
{
    key_t key;
    char *virtualaddr;
    int get, put;
    int shmid;
    #define BUF_SIZE    BUFSIZ
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];

    key = ftok("anyfile", 'R');
    #define N   4
    atomic_int *a;  // where the process counter is at the end of the shared mem
    shmid = shmget(key, 1024*N + sizeof*a, 0644|IPC_CREAT); // 1 kiB per process
    if (0 > shmid)
    {
        perror("Shared Mem creation error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    //Attaching the shared mem to my address space (available across fork)
    virtualaddr = shmat(shmid, (void *)0, 0);
    a = (void *)&virtualaddr[1024*N];
    *a = 0;

    //Create two semaphore sets, get and put; Linux initializes the values to 0.
    get = semget('g', N, IPC_CREAT|0644);
    put = semget('p', N, IPC_CREAT|0644);

    for (int n = 0; n < N; ++n)
    // N children A
    switch (fork())
    {
        case -1:
            printf("Error forking child A!\n");
            exit(1);
        case 0:
            printf("\nChild A%d executing...\n", n);
            //Referring the semaphore sets:
            get = semget('g', 0, 0);
            put = semget('p', 0, 0);
            //Child A writing in shared mem
            sprintf(virtualaddr+1024*n, "Hello world, I'm child A%d\n", n);
            //Child A signalling that now child B can write
            semop(get, &(struct sembuf){ n, 1 }, 1);
            //Child A waiting for Child B to write..
            semop(put, &(struct sembuf){ n, -1 }, 1);
            //Child A reading from shared mem
            strcpy(buf, virtualaddr+1024*n);
            printf("Message received child A%d: %s", n, buf);
            printf("Exiting child A%d...\n", n);
            _exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    for (int n = 0; n < N; ++n)
    // N children B
    switch (fork())
    {
        case -1:
            printf("Error forking child B!\n");
            exit(1);
        case 0:
            printf("\nChild B%d executing...\n", n);
            //Referring the semaphore sets:
            get = semget('g', 0, 0);
            put = semget('p', 0, 0);
            int i = (*a)++; // [somewhat] randomly select one of the A processes
            //Waiting till Child A has written
            semop(get, &(struct sembuf){ i, -1 }, 1);
            //Now child B can read from shared memory
            strcpy(buf, virtualaddr+1024*i);
            //Child B writing in shared mem
            sprintf(virtualaddr+1024*i, "Hello world, I'm child B%d\n", n);
            //Signalling that now Child A can read.
            semop(put, &(struct sembuf){ i, 1 }, 1);
            printf("Exiting child B%d...\n", n);
            printf("Message received child B%d: %s", n, buf);
            _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    printf("Parent waiting for children completion...\n");
    while (wait(NULL) > 0) ;
    if (errno != ECHILD)
    {
        printf("Error waiting.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Parent finishing.\n");
    //Deleting semaphore sets:
    semctl(get, 0, IPC_RMID);
    semctl(put, 0, IPC_RMID);
    //Deleting Shared Memory.
    shmctl (shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```